# Pod Auto destory is possible when it is not going for READY state?

Tags: kubernetes

Consider i have 2 containers inside pod.

1. Configured startup probe on these 2 containers
2. It will come to READY state only when both probes are successfully executed and satisfied
3. If one of the probe is failed, I may remain one container in not in READY state.

I need to have condition here :
If any one of the container inside my pod is not getting UP and READY state. After few tries in probe.
I need to destroy this POD from the node.

Is that possible ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do so by combination of a readiness probe, a liveness probe, and a pod termination policy.

1. Configure a readiness probe for each container in the pod to determine if it’s ready to accept traffic.
2. Configure a liveness probe for each container to check if it’s running and healthy. If the probe fails,the container will be restarted.
3. Set the pod’s termination policy to ‘Failure’. This means that if any container in the pod fails, the entire pod will be terminated.

Refer to the [liveness probe best practices](https://www.fairwinds.com/blog/a-guide-to-understanding-kubernetes-liveness-probes-best-practices#:%7E:text=A%20few%20other%20liveness%20probe%20best%20practices:%7E:text=Understanding%20liveness%20probe%20settings) written by Adam Zahorscak for more information.

Comment: what is the field you are referring here "pod termination policy"

restartPolicy ?
but the 
expectation here is : 
I need to test the probe for few tries, and if connection not established all the time then trigger termination of pod

Comment: Modify the values for **terminationGracePeriodSeconds** and probe parameters to meet your needs.